# Can't make two clients communicate with each other

Tags: c, sockets, server, pthreads

I'm developing a Multi room chat in C for a University project.

I'm pretty close to finishing it, but there's one big problem: I can't make two clients communicate with each other. Only client A can send messages to client B, while client B receive them (and cannot send them).

I will explain in details what my idea is, and why I think it doesn't work:

In this project, i have to create a server for chatting. There has to be rooms with a theme (politics, videogames, etc), and clients can connect to them. But... the chat has to be bidirectional. So, 1 client can communicate with 1 client in that room.

Think about Omegle: you put a keyword, and it matches with another person who has the same keyword.

To implement this, i created a struc called clientList, where i store every information needed about clients when they connect to the server. The way i implemented the pairing is the following:

Every client has a room (chosen by the user). When you connect and choose the room, the server reads all clientList. When it finds another client who wants to connect to the same room, and has still not been paired with anyone else, then they save each other's sockets, so they can communicate.

Here is the code of the server.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "proto.h"
#include "server.h"


// Variabili Globali
int server_sockfd = 0, client_sockfd = 0;
ClientList *root, *now;
int room1Clients = 0, room2Clients = 0;
int leave_flag = 0;
ClientList *np;
char chosenRoom[ROOM_CHOICE] = {};
char recv_buffer[LENGTH_MSG] = {};
char send_buffer[LENGTH_SEND] = {};


// Metodi

void catch_ctrl_c_and_exit(int sig) {
    ClientList *tmp;
    while (root != NULL) {
        printf("\nClose socketfd: %d\n", root->socket);
        close(root->socket); // close all socket include server_sockfd
        tmp = root;
        root = root->link;
        free(tmp);
    }
    printf("Bye\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


void send_to_other_client(ClientList* np, char tmp_buffer[]) {
      printf("Sockfd: %d sends to Sockfd %d: \"%s\" \n", np->socket, np->pairSock, tmp_buffer);
      send(np->pairSock, tmp_buffer, LENGTH_SEND, 0);
}


void pairing_with_client(ClientList *np){
  ClientList *tmp = root->link;
  printf("Looking for matching...\n");
  while (1){
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        if (np->socket != tmp->socket && (strcmp(np->room, tmp->room) == 0) && tmp->paired == 0 && tmp->socket != np->pairSock) {
   
            np->pairSock = tmp->socket;
            np->paired = 1;
            printf("Matching found! socketfd: %d has been paired with socketfd:%d\n", np->socket, np->pairSock);
            return;
        }
        tmp = tmp->link;
    }

  }
}



void client_handler(void *p_client) {


    char nickname[NAME_LENGTH] = {};
    ClientList *np = (ClientList *)p_client;

    // Naming
    if (recv(np->socket, nickname, NAME_LENGTH, 0) <= 0) {
        printf("%s didn't input name.\n", np->ip);
        leave_flag = 1;
    } else {
        strncpy(np->name, nickname, NAME_LENGTH);
        printf("%s(%s)(%d) join the chatroom.\n", np->name, np->ip, np->socket);
        sprintf(send_buffer, "%s join the chatroom.", np->name);
    }


    // Scelta della stanza
    sprintf(send_buffer, "\nWelcome to RandomChat!\nChoose the room.\n\n[%d/10] Politics\n[%d/10] Videogames\n", room1Clients, room2Clients);
    send(np->socket, send_buffer, LENGTH_SEND, 0);

    if (recv(np->socket, chosenRoom, ROOM_CHOICE, 0) <= 0) {
        printf("%s hasn't chosen a room.\n", np->ip);
        leave_flag = 1;
    } else {
        printf("%s(%s)(%d) chose the room %s.\n", np->name, np->ip, np->socket, chosenRoom);

        if (strcmp(chosenRoom, "1") == 0){
          room1Clients++;
        } else if (strcmp(chosenRoom, "2") == 0){
          room2Clients++;
        }
    }

    // Pairing con utente
    strncpy(chosenRoom, np->room, ROOM_CHOICE); // saving the room chosen by the

client

    pairing_with_client(np);

    // Conversation

    while (1) {
        if (leave_flag == 1) {
            break;
        }
        int receive = recv(np->socket, recv_buffer, LENGTH_MSG, 0);
        if (receive > 0) {
            if (strlen(recv_buffer) == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            sprintf(send_buffer, "%s：%s", np->name, recv_buffer);
        } else if (receive == 0 || strcmp(recv_buffer, "exit") == 0) {
            printf("%s(%s)(%d) leave the chatroom.\n", np->name, np->ip, np->socket);
            sprintf(send_buffer, "%s leave the chatroom.", np->name);
            leave_flag = 1;
        } else {
            printf("Fatal Error: -1\n");
            leave_flag = 1;
        }
        send_to_other_client(np, send_buffer);
    }

    // Remove Node
    close(np->socket);
    if (np == now) { // remove an edge node
        now = np->prev;
        now->link = NULL;
    } else { // remove a middle node
        np->prev->link = np->link;
        np->link->prev = np->prev;
    }
    free(np);
}




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //signal(SIGINT, catch_ctrl_c_and_exit);

    // Creating socket
    server_sockfd = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (server_sockfd == -1) {
        printf("Failed creating socket.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

     
    struct sockaddr_in server_info, client_info;
    int s_addrlen = sizeof(server_info);
    int c_addrlen = sizeof(client_info);
    memset(&server_info, 0, s_addrlen);
    memset(&client_info, 0, c_addrlen);
    server_info.sin_family = PF_INET;
    server_info.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_info.sin_port = htons(8888);

    // Bind e Listen
    int opt = 1;
    setsockopt(server_sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt));

    bind(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_info, s_addrlen);
    listen(server_sockfd, 5);

    // Print server IP
    getsockname(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &server_info, (socklen_t*) &s_addrlen);
    printf("Server avviato: %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(server_info.sin_addr), ntohs(server_info.sin_port));

    // Initial linked list for clients
    root = newNode(server_sockfd, inet_ntoa(server_info.sin_addr));
    now = root;

    while (1) {
        client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &client_info, (socklen_t*) &c_addrlen);

        // Print Client IP
        getpeername(client_sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &client_info, (socklen_t*) &c_addrlen);
        printf("Client %s:%d come in.\n", inet_ntoa(client_info.sin_addr), ntohs(client_info.sin_port));

        // Append linked list for clients
        ClientList *c = newNode(client_sockfd, inet_ntoa(client_info.sin_addr));
        c->prev = now;
        now->link = c;
        now = c;

        pthread_t id;
        if (pthread_create(&id, NULL, (void *)client_handler, (void *)c) != 0) {
            perror("Create pthread error!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem happens (i think) in the function pairing_with_client. What happens in the output is that the first client who connects prints "Looking for matching...", and never returns from the function. When another clients connects, it instantly finds client A, prints "Matching found!", and saves its socket to communicate with him. So, when client B sends a message, it works. But client A? Can only receive. That is because (i think) i haven't used any synchronization, so the clientList for client A never updates, and so it is stuck there.

If that's the problem, then i need a hand doing this. If you think it's not this, well... i'm in big trouble and need a bigger hand.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I would start by checking return codes from bind, listen, and other calls to make sure they are succeeding.

Comment: The clients succeed to connect to the server, but as i wrote in the last part of my question, only one client connect to the another one.

Comment: Looks like your pairing function only makes a pairing one way, not both ways?

Comment: Since each clients have it's own thread, it update itself when pairing occurs.

Comment: Your example program is incomplete, and does not compile. Please try to post a complete [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be properly inspected. That said, you appear to be starting a new thread for each connection, and sharing a set of global variables between these threads with no synchronization. This will result in various [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#In_software) cropping up throughout the program.